# Почему неправильно срабатывает if else в js?

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой код:

```
var nveF = +1250
if (nveF < +1200, nveF > +979) {
    /*Какое либо действие*/
}
else if (nveF > +1199) {
    /*Какое либо действие*/
}
```

Почему срабатывает первый if ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может вы хотели так?

```
if (nveF < 1200 && nveF > 979) {
    /*Какое либо действие*/
}
```